# Obtaining a flat list of all blobs in a .git/objects/ folder

Tags: linux, git, command-line

In the `.git/objects/` folder there are many folders with files within such as `ab/cde...`. I understand that these are actually blobs `abcde...`

Is there a way to obtain a flat file listing of all blobs under `.git/objects/` with no `/` being used a delimitor between `ab` and `cde` in the example above? For e.g.

```
abcde....
ab812....
74axs...
```

I tried

```
/.git/objects$ du -a .
```

This does list recursively all folders and files within the `/objects/` folder but the blobs are not listed since the command lists the folder followed by the filename (as the OS recognizes them, as opposed to git). Furthermore, the `du` command does not provide a flat listing in a single column -- it provides the output in two columns with a numeric entry (disk usage) in the first column.

Comment: The `.git/objects/<two hex digits>/<remaining hex digits>` files are only the *loose* objects; *packed* objects take space too. There are multiple different size questions you can answer: two for loose objects, three for packed objects. These are: how much disk space does this object use directly; how big is this object once it's unpacked/loose; how big is the uncompressed object?

Comment: There are four object types: commit, tree, (annotated) tag, and blob. The `--filter` option, new in Git 2.32 for `git rev-list`, lets you trim the set to one particular type. Otherwise, read the object type (available from the object header or the `mode` depending on what you're looking at) to find out what kind of object this is.

Comment: (1) Are the packed objects in `/.git/objects/pack` folder? (2) Are the four object types (loose or packed) also fully contained in `/.git/objects/` (3) Is there a guarantee that the folder structure of `/.git/objects/` always of type `subfolder/file` with no more contained subfolders?

Comment: Additionally, the number of lines returned by the two answers below are different. The sed method returns fewer lines on my machine as compared to the git rev-list method. Perhaps this is because, as you mentioned, the sed method only lists the loose objects while the git rev-list method will also indicate the loose object as well as other objects (the packed objects unpacked?) ?

Comment: 1: yes. 2: the type and unpacked size of the object is encoded in the object's data header, so you have to read the first N bytes (N varies) to find it. 3: not formally but since other implementations of Git read and sometimes even write Git repositories, that's changing now (some of the file formats are being redefined as "protocol"). 4: there can be *unreachable* objects, so even packed vs loose, rev-list won't necessarily find *all* objects. These are the ones that `git fsck` might report as "unreachable" and `git gc` might delete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should start round here (git version 2.37.2):

```
git rev-list --all --objects --filter=object:type=blob
```

Doing it this way offers the advantage of not *only* checking the directory where the *unpacked* objects are but also the objects that are already packed (which are not in that directory anymore).

Comment: There seems to be a typo: `fatal: invalid filter-spec 'object:type=blob'` is thrown as an error

Comment: It's working fine over here. Perhaps it's a version problem. Check `git help rev-list`.

Comment: Mine is git version 2.31.1.  But I got the same error. I think @eftshift0's approach is better.

Comment: @eftshift0 : `git rev-list --all --objects` works on my version of git and is also very useful for me--relating a blob to a file.

Answer (score 2):

## If you are in the .git/objects/ folder

Try this.

`find . -type f  | sed -e 's/.git\/objects\///' | sed -e 's/\///'`

`sed -e` requires the sed script, which means a find/replace pattern.

`'s/.git\/objects\///'` finds `.git/objects/` and replace it to `''` which is nothing. therefore `sed` command remove the pattern.

`\` in the pattern is an escape character.

After first sed command ends,
the results will be (in linux.)

```
61/87c3f3d6c61c1a6ea475afb64265b83e73ec26
```

To remove `/` which refers a directory sign,

`sed -e 's/\///'`

## If you are in the directory which contains `.git`

`find .git/objects/ -type f  | sed -e 's/.git\/objects\///' | sed -e 's/\///'`

try this.

Comment: The second sed command also works just fine. Thanks for the non-git general answer! If you don't mind, could I request you to add a brief explanation of why the sed command works?

Comment: I added the a brief explanation

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I have tested this command on two machines -- one running WSL and another running native Ubuntu. The output from WSL comes sorted, while the one from Ubuntu does not come sorted. Is there a way to ensure that the flat file output is sorted?

Comment: add `| sort`. example is `find .git/objects/ -type f  | sed -e 's/.git\/objects\///' | sed 's/\///' | sort`